# tomcat 7 with AWS

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services

Created an instance with EC2 and deployed. Everything working fine but one problem is:
i should access my application with:
http://ec2-50.31.43.compute1.aws.com/applicationName or Is there a way to avoid the applicationName in the URL.
I should be able to access my application with URL:
http://ec2-50.31.43.compute1.aws.com/applicationName

I tried by making my application as default in the tomcat by adding the below in the server.xml

WEB-INF/web.xml

this works if i access the URL with domain name
But in my application other links are not working. 
Also tried by renaming my war file as ROOT and then also the same issue exists.

Is there any other solution to so that i can access my application with the domain name with all my links working.

Comment: "this works if i access the URL with domain name But in my application other links are not working" - show us the links that don't work and how you create them (JSP?).

Answer (score 0):

Store your app as `ROOT.war` and add `<base href="http://my:8080/root/url">` at the top of your JSP pages.